# Derive Euler equation: Nabla vs. index notation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, flow

Given the laws for mass and momentum conservation,
\begin{align}
\quad \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\rho\,v_i)&=0 \\
\quad \frac{\partial(\rho\,v_i)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\rho\,v_iv_j+p\,\delta_{ij}\right)&=\rho\,g_i
\end{align}

I would like to get to the Euler equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t}+\left(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla\right)\vec{v}=-\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p+\vec{g}
\end{equation}

My first idea was to expand all the terms in both equations and see if this brings me any closer to a solution. I don't know much of index notation yet, so I tried to rewrite the equations back to all Nablas where applicable. Let's begin with the continuity equation:
\begin{equation}
\quad \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\rho\,\vec{v})=0 \quad \iff \quad \quad \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+(\nabla\rho)\cdot\vec{v}+\rho(\nabla\cdot\vec{v})=0 
\end{equation}

When I try to do the same for the momentum equation, I run into trouble because I don't know how to handle the scond term on the LHS, which reads $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(\rho\,v_iv_j\right)$. This looks like the vector gradient $(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}$, but only if I omit the mass density $\rho$. Since in general $\rho=\rho(x,t)$, I assume that I cannot pull $\rho$ out of the vector gradient. How should I proceed form here?

Comment: Uh, why not use the product rule, $(u\cdot v)'=u'\cdot v+u\cdot v'$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the product rule, rewrite the conservation of mass equation as

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\rho\frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_j} - v_j\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_j}$$

We've also relabeled the dummy index $i\rightarrow j$. Then the product rule on the momentum conservation equation is

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}v_i + \rho\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_j}v_i v_j + \rho\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}v_j + \rho v_i \frac{\partial v_j}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} = \rho g_i $$

Plugging in $\partial \rho/\partial t$ from the first equation, we see four terms cancel and are left with

$$\rho\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial t} + \rho v_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i} + \rho g_i$$

Notice the second term on the left is contracted over the dummy index $j$. The free index $i$ denotes the components of the vectors. Replacing the components with the vector they represent (and dividing by $\rho$)

$$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} + (\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec{v} = \frac{-1}{\rho}\vec{\nabla}p + \vec{g}$$

Comment: I understand that the divergence can be written as $\nabla\cdot\vec{v}=\partial v_i / \partial x_i = \partial_i v_i$, likewise for the "standard" gradient we have $(\nabla v)_i=\partial v / \partial x_i = \partial_i v$. But how can I "see" that the expression $\rho v_j (\partial v_i/ \partial x_j)$ results in $(\vec{v}\cdot\nabla)\vec{v}$?

Comment: @user358572 The dummy index, $j$, is summed over which forms the inner product. It's easier to see explicitly in 3D Cartesian coordinates: $v_j\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j} = v_x\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x} + v_y\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial y} + v_z\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial z} = (\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\nabla})v_i$.